# What type of database it is more secure for my mobile application?

Tags: android, database, security

I'm doing a new mobile application with Android which it's storing information in a database and I want to know about what it's the most secure database or if there is some another service that could replace it and will be more secure.

I'm really new in this field and I don't want to have problems later, so I want to start my app as secure as possible since the beginning.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to store something locally, [SQLCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/) probably is the right choice. Anyway as Android apps are very weak to reverse engineering, that will not save your client's data if a malicious one will have a strong intention to steal it. So if you have not applied some additional protection (string encryption, integrity protection, method calls hiding,..) to your APK it is better to avoid storing sensitive data on a device.

Comment: @IvanKinash Thank you man! I will considerate it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you mean secure ?

Security is an entire different field. Use cryptography to store the data.

If storing passwords use hashing, there are libraries for that. Otherwise, MySQL should do just fine.

Comment: Yes, I mean how to store sensitive information for make their access more difficult for other people. Or to stop backdoors or attacks like this. I'm really new both security and Android. Thanks for answer! :)

Comment: I suggest you study cryptography. This is a nice [link](http://www.crypto-textbook.com/). It doesn't really matter what database you use. You can choose oracle, but unless you secure your data, there is no security.

Comment: Thank you again man. I'm very glad for your answers :)

Comment: @Error404 Sure, but write your own codes. Never copy, the copied codes are what weakens your security. use good libs like OpenSSL. Good luck

Comment: For sure, you were in your right own. This code it is copy. I mark your answer better because I saw that you have more idea than him. I prefer a short answer than a code that it is not from someone. Thank you again for all :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec;
import android.util.Base64;

public class SimpleCrypto {

    private String charsetName = "UTF8";
    private String algorithm = "DES";
    private int base64Mode = Base64.DEFAULT;

    public String getCharsetName() {
        return charsetName;
    }

    public void setCharsetName(String charsetName) {
        this.charsetName = charsetName;
    }

    public String getAlgorithm() {
        return algorithm;
    }

    public void setAlgorithm(String algorithm) {
        this.algorithm = algorithm;
    }

    public int getBase64Mode() {
        return base64Mode;
    }

    public void setBase64Mode(int base64Mode) {
        this.base64Mode = base64Mode;
    }

    public String encrypt(String key, String data) {
        if (key == null || data == null)
            return null;
        try {
            DESKeySpec desKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes(charsetName));
            SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
            SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(desKeySpec);
            byte[] dataBytes = data.getBytes(charsetName);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return Base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(dataBytes), base64Mode);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String decrypt(String key, String data) {
        if (key == null || data == null)
            return null;
        try {
            byte[] dataBytes = Base64.decode(data, base64Mode);
            DESKeySpec desKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes(charsetName));
            SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
            SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(desKeySpec);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            byte[] dataBytesDecrypted = (cipher.doFinal(dataBytes));
            return new String(dataBytesDecrypted);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
private SimpleCrypto simpleCrypto = new SimpleCrypto();

String MasterPassword = "qssfFs32fFwada";

String encryptedText = simpleCrypto.encrypt(MasterPassword, "Hello World");
Log.i(encryptedText, encryptedText);

String decryptedText = decrypt(MasterPassword, encryptedText);
Log.i(decryptedText, decryptedText);
```

Of course you have to change the "Master Password" with something else and save it to string.xml

Comment: Thank you man! I put your answer marked because I think it is more elaborate.

Comment: @Error404 you marked his answer because he gave you ready made codes.

Comment: @Mayank I though he did his code. If I could I would mark both answers. What can I do?